# Return substring up to first digit

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substring

I am trying to group rows by a field that either has the pattern `[:alpha:][:digit:].*` or `[:alpha:][:alpha:][:digit:].*` by the substring up to but excluding the digit. i.e. the returned substring will either have one letter, or two.

I am thinking something along the lines of:

```
SELECT
  LEFT(postcode,IF(ISDIGIT(postcode,2),1,2)) AS area,
  COUNT(*) AS num
FROM addresses
GROUP BY
  LEFT(postcode,IF(ISDIGIT(postcode,2),1,2))
```

Except of course there is no `ISDIGIT()` function.

I was also thinking of something similar to `LEFT(postcode,POSITION_REGEX("\d" IN postcode))` but obviously that doesn't exist either :-/

Database server is running MySQL 4.1.24
Upgrading to 5.0 is possible but would require downtime and hasn't been done yet as it hasn't been necessary so far.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589632/splitting-elements-of-a-string-across-multiple-columns/7590413#7590413

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    LEFT(postcode, IF(postcode REGEXP '^.[[:digit:]]', 1, 2)) AS area,
    COUNT(*) AS num
FROM addresses
GROUP BY area
```